# Block sms on ios6

Tags: ios, ios6, jailbreak

I'm building for a jail-broken device and I want to block incoming messages.
I'm trying to hook _ingestIncomingCTMessage, but it has no result( it seems not working on ios6). How else I can block sms in ios6?

Comment: A naive question: why do you want to block incoming sms?

Comment: @AlexWien I imagine it could be useful for a lot of tweaks, since it allows you to conditionally block texts depending on the sender/content. You could make a text trigger an Activator action or query a device for information, without the text being visible in the thread later on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is quite tricky. Apple made major changes in this area. It's very easy on iOS 5 but on iOS 6 I couldn't find easy way to do it yet.
First, you need to observer __kIMChatItemsDidChangeNotification notification using CTTelephonyCenter. I'm doing it in dylib injected in SpringBoard. Not sure but this may be important.

```
CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver(CTTelephonyCenterGetDefault(), NULL, Callback, NULL, NULL, CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviourHold);

void Callback(CFNotificationCenterRef, void*, NSString* notification, const void*, NSDictionary* userInfo)
{
    if (![notification isEqualToString:@"__kIMChatItemsDidChangeNotification"])
    {
        return;
    }

    for (IMChatItem* chatItem in userInfo[@"__kIMChatItemsKey"])
    {
        IMMessage* msg = [chatItem message];//Incoming message object
        NSString* text = [[msg text] string];//message text
        NSString* sender = [[msg sender] ID];//message sender

        [[IMDMessageStore sharedInstance] performBlock:^{
            IMDChatRecordDeleteChatForGUID([NSString stringWithFormat:@"SMS;-;%@", sender]);
        }];
    }
}
```

Last bit is very important. You can't just delete message. You need to do it on a specific internal thread or you'll get an error. This is why I'm using `IMDMessageStore`. It's `performBlock:` method executes block on this special thread. 
`IMDChatRecordDeleteChatForGUID` function can be found in IMDPersistence.framework. It deletes whole message tree (chat/conversation) with specific GUID. I couldn't find a way to retrive this GUID so I'm building it manually using GUIDs from SMS sqlite database as a sample.

To delete just one message you can use `IMDMessageRecordDeleteMessagesForGUIDs([NSArray arrayWithObject:[msg guid]]);`

`IMChatItem` and `IMMessage` can be found in `IMCore.framework`. `IMDMessageStore` is in `IMDaemonCore.framework`.

This is easy part. Now when you receive message and block it this way you will see that it still shows in MobileSMS app, you still might get bullein notification, you still get badge telling you there is unread message. But if you open SMS sqlite database you will see that message was  indeed deleted. Blocking these is not that easy.

1. Bullein. In SpringBoard you need to hook `BBServer` method `publishBulletin:destinations:alwaysOnLockScreen:`. First argument is BBBulletin object. If it's incoming message bulletin it's `section` property equals `com.apple.MobileSMS`. To block bulletin just return from this method and don't call original implementation.
2. MobileSMS app badge. There is ChatKit.serviceBundle that's being loaded in SpringBoard when there is incoming SMS. You need to hook two methods in `MessagesBadgeController` - `_madridChatRegistered:` and `_madridUnreadCountChanged:`. Their first argument is `NSNotification` object with `object` property containing `IMChat` object. Again, just return from these methods to prevent badge changes.
3. MobileSMS app. To stop it from showing already deleted messages I'm
   hooking quite a lot of methods. I will just give you the list:
   `SMSApplication _receivedMessage:`, `CKTranscriptController
   _messageReceived:`, `CKConversationList _handleRegistryDidRegisterChatNotification:, _handleRegistryDidLoadChatNotification:, hasActiveConversations, unreadCount`. `CKConversationController
   _chatParticipantsChangedNotification:, updateConversationList`, `CKMessagesController showConversation:animate:forceToTranscript:`

About ChatKit.serviceBundle. To hook it's classes you need to wait when SpringBoard actually loads it. This is done in `SBPluginManager loadPluginBundle:`. Bundle identifier should be equal to `com.apple.SMSPlugin`. Only then you can hook methods.

That's it. Quite a lot of work but it's working perfectly - no sign of incoming message, even if you were in MobileSMS application when message arrived.

I'm sure there is easier way to do it. There is com.apple.imagent daemon which sends notifications to various iOS components. It's very important in iOS 6 messaging system. Good place to start.

Comment: I cant found function: IMDChatRecordDeleteChatForGUID inIMDPersistence.framework

Comment: @user1561904, it's there, just try calling it. Remeber that C functions exported with leading underscore. So in IDA, for example, you'll see _IMDChatRecordDeleteChatForGUID function, not IMDChatRecordDeleteChatForGUID.

Comment: My Problem is message still showing at Inbox, but when touch to read it, it's gone

Comment: I think this is because com.apple.imagent thinks there is messages and tells that Messages application. But when you read message and Messages app tries to actualy read it from database it's gone becase this message is deleted from SMS.db As I said in your question, try killing imagent. It will reload SMS.db contents and inbox will be empty. This works, I tried it yesterday. Personally, I don't like killing processes so I'm hooking MobileSMS methods to stop it from showing deleted messages. Read my answers, it's all there and tested many times.

Comment: Hooking MobileSMS is difficult for me, How can I killing "com.apple.imagent" 
Another question: I catch "kCTMessageReceivedNotification", I used this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681995/how-to-get-the-message-when-receiving-the-kctmessagereceivednotification-notif to get sms content, but sometime, it is null, Why?

Comment: You can kill it like this `launchctl stop com.apple.imagent`. He will automatically relaunch and reload SMS.db contents. As for notification, I don't use it on both iOS 5 and 6 so I can't help you with that. On iOS 5 there is much more easy and reliable way of blocking incoming SMS. Above is how I'm doing it on iOS 6. Again, reliable, but not very easy. If you want to know how to do it properly on iOS 5 without using notifications, ask another question.

Comment: OK :D
Without get from "sms.db", any ways to get sms content when I received ""kCTMessageReceivedNotification"

Comment: Having read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681995/how-to-get-the-message-when-receiving-the-kctmessagereceivednotification-notif , I remember trying to use kCTMessageReceivedNotification and getting empty contents too. This is due to this message in console "unknown CommCenter[31] <Notice>: removing received message 2147483648". It's CoreTelephony notification so CommCenter must be removing message object before we can read it. This is why I dropped it on iOS 6 and found solution above. On iOS 5 there is much better way.

Comment: That solution can get "normal" message or only iMessage.
By the way: I used system"launchctl stop com.apple.imagent" but at Inbox, message is gone but still appear "sender number"

Comment: I haven't tested it with iMessage. But inside iOS there is no clear difference between SMS, MMS and iMessages. It's all instant messages using identical objects. You can see in the code above that everything has "IM" prefix. So on iOS 6 I think it should work with iMessages. You don't need to implement everything to test it. Just try catching __kIMChatItemsDidChangeNotification with different kinds of messages.

Comment: "I used system launchctl stop com.apple.imagent but at Inbox, message is gone but still appear sender number" - it's off-topic. Better ask this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939771/delete-message-on-ios-6/16451289

Comment: On your method, Did you used "IMCor.framework" or another framwork, can you tell me and maybe, send me that :D

Comment: `IMChatItem` and `IMMessage` can be found in `IMCore.framework`. `IMDMessageStore` is in `IMDaemonCore.framework`

Comment: I'm working with xcode 3, but when i add IMCore.framework, Error: gcc 4.2. 
How can I fix that? plx help

Comment: Can you tell who it can be done "To hook it's classes you need to wait when SpringBoard actually loads" i mean how to wait

Comment: "This is done in 'SBPluginManager loadPluginBundle:'. Bundle identifier should be equal to com.apple.SMSPlugin. Only then you can hook methods"

Comment: Can you send me this project?

Answer (score 9):

Found much better and simpler way. Just as I thought `com.apple.imagent` daemon is very important and it's him who is handling `kCTMessageReceivedNotification`. This is why we get empty message object when handling `kCTMessageReceivedNotification` yourself - `com.apple.imagent` is removing it from `CTMessageCenter`.

We need to hook just two methods but finding and hooking them is quite tricky. Both methods are hooked in `com.apple.imagent` daemon.

First, `SMSServiceSession -(void)_processReceivedMessage:(CTMessage*)msg`. This is where incoming message is being initially processed, saved to the SMS database and passed to all other iOS components. Problem is there is no information about this API anywhere. `com.apple.imagent` appears to be not using it if you disassemble it. It's because it's being loaded manually at runtime.

When `com.apple.imagent` is started he's loading several plugins. The one that we need is located in `/System/Library/Messages/PlugIns/SMS.imservice/` - this is where `SMSServiceSession` is implemented. You will not find binary in there because just like all the frameworks it's compiled into `/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld/dyld_shared_cache_armv7`. IDA recognizes this file and let's you choose which binary inside of it you want to disassemble.

To delete incoming message and prevent any notifications about it you need to call `[[CTMessageCenter sharedMessageCenter] acknowledgeIncomingMessageWithId:[msg messageId]]` and return from `_processReceivedMessage:` without calling original implementation. Calling `CTMessageCenter` method is important because it queues incoming messages.

Now we need to find a way to know when`SMS.imservice` plugin is being actually loaded. Initially imagent only creates `NSBundle` objects without loading any code. So you can't hook any methods because classes are not yet loaded from the plugins. To solve this we can hook `IMDService -(void)loadServiceBundle` method from private `IMDaemonCore.framework`. Call original implementation and you can hook methods inside the plugin. To determine which plugin is being loaded you can check bundle identifier in `IMDService -(NSBundle*)bundle`.

This method works only with SMS and MMS messages. iMessages are processed in similar way but with different plugin - `/System/Library/Messages/PlugIns/iMessage.imservice`. Hooking `MessageServiceSession -(void)_handler:(id) incomingMessage:(id) encryptionType:(id) messageID:(id) fromIdentifier:(id) fromToken:(id) timeStamp:(id) storageContext:(id) allowRetry:(char) completionBlock:(id)` should do the trick.

**UPDATE**

Works on iOS 7

**UPDATE 2**

On iOS 8 everything works the same way except you need to hook different `SMSServiceSession` method - `-(void)_processReceivedDictionary:(NSDictionary*)msg`. Dictionary will contain all SMS message contents.

If you don't want to rewrite everything for iOS 8 you can reuse your old code. Incoming SMS notification is handled by hidden non-exported C callback function - you can't hook it. First, it calls `SMSServiceSession -(id)_convertCTMessageToDictionary:(CTMessage*)msg requiresUpload:(BOOL*)upload` to convert SMS message object to dictionary. Then it calls `SMSServiceSession -(void)_processReceivedDictionary:(NSDictionary*)msg` to process message. Finally, it calls `SMSServiceSession -(BOOL)relayDictionaryToPeers:(NSDictionary*)msg requiresUpload:(BOOL)upload` to notify all other iOS components about incoming message.

To block SMS you need to hook `_convertCTMessageToDictionary` where you can use the same code you used on previous iOS versions. You also need to hook both `_processReceivedDictionary` and `relayDictionaryToPeers` to actually block incoming message. Just return from them without calling original implementation. You can set some global variable in `_convertCTMessageToDictionary` and check and reset it in other methods. It's perfectly safe to do it that way - these methods are called one after another synchronously. That C callback function is the only places where these methods are called.

Comment: Sorry if being naive, but `%hook SMSServiceSession -(void)_processReceivedMessage:(id)msg{ %log; %orig; }` does nothing. Have tried with both `Bundles = ("com.apple.imagent",)` and `Executables = ( "imagent" )` in my `.plist` file. Should I try something else?

Comment: `SMS.imservice` (SMSServiceSession is inside of it) is being loaded manually into imagent, it's not linked at compile time thus you can't just hook methods whenever you want. Theos hooks methods in dylib constructor but at this point `SMS.imservice` is not loaded. That's why we need `loadServiceBundle` - this is where plugins are actually loaded into imagent. Only then you can hook `_processReceivedMessage`. Until then it doesn't exist. I think you need to use MobileSubstrate API manually for this one.

Comment: It took me ages to understand the Logos tweaks! I guess it will be really hardcore to start with MobileSubstrate API now…!

Comment: Did you manage to block outgoing messages as well? Being able to send messages without them appearing in Messages.app?

Comment: In my project I still use other method that I described here (in accepted answer). It deals with sent and received messages. If you want to use method above with SMS.imservice I think you can block sent messages by hooking `SMSServiceSession -(void)_processMessageSent:(unsigned int)msgID` but I don't know for sure. I haven't done any research in this area.

Comment: @AlexandreBlin, check out my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872553/send-programmatically-sms-on-jailbreak-device/20425853#20425853

Comment: @creker, Hi. Did you manage to port this for iOS 8? The bundle isn't loaded in iOS 8!

Comment: @Hamed, yes. Everything is the same except you need to hook different method in `SMSServiceSession`. I don't have the source code with me and don't remember which one it is.

Comment: @creker, Thanks for reply! I checked dyld_shared_chache and found `[SMSServiceSession _processReceivedDictionary:]` to be the function you say (I guess!). But I have another problem. `IMDService` doesn't load the bundle at all so I can't hook the function.

Comment: @creker, Oops! It was my problem. This function is hooked the same way as iOS 7. And `[SMSServiceSession _processReceivedDictionary:]` works. It's argument is a dictionary containing message data. By not calling the original function the sms is blocked! Thanks again:)

Answer (score 1):

i have a better solution to block all SMS messages

```
%hook CKConversationListController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    %orig;

    CKConversationList *list = MSHookIvar<CKConversationList *>(self, "_conversationList");

    if ([list count]) {
        [deleteAll release];
    }
}

%new
- (void)deleteAll:(id)sender {

    CKConversationList *list = MSHookIvar<CKConversationList *>(self, "_conversationList");
    UITableView *messages = MSHookIvar<UITableView *>(self, "_table");

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < [[list conversations] count]; i++) {
        [list deleteConversationAtIndex:i];
    }

    [messages reloadData];
}
%end
```

Comment: This doesn't block anything. Bulletin is not blocked. MobileSMS badge is not blocked. Only thing this code does is deleting everything once you launch MobileSMS. Moreover, if you launch it after SMS was received you will still see this SMS.